# Creating Trigger after insert date from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm struggling with creating trigger.I have 2 different tables called Manager and Department.I got departments in my department table and got a row about keep how many worker got each other department.Example like i got software department and i wanna add new worker which is working on software department and i need to update my row which is keep number of workers.

Comment: Hi Ivarrson, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could edit your question to give the table structure and what have you tried till now.

Comment: Why store the data of the number in the first place? This is some morning that could be easily worked out with a query; perhaps in a view

Comment: Because when i want to delete a department i need to check is there a any worker.If there s no worker i can delete department. Otherwise i can't. Btw this is Web project and using. Net core. Any other solutions would be great

Comment: For that you should use a `Foreign Key`. Don't use a trigger

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this syntax to setup your trigger

```
create trigger tr_insertIntoFirstTableFromSecondTable on tblFirstTable for insert
as
begin
    --declare the variables to hold your values as necessary
    declare @value1 int = 0;
    declare @value2 int = 0;
    declare @value3 int = 0;

    select @value1 = column1, @value2 = column2, @value3 = column3 from INSERTED

    insert into tblSecondTable (column1,column2,column3) values (@value1, @value2, @value3);

end
```